# Crystal Report asking for login on client machine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have passed the login information for the crystal report through code, which is put below. But when i install the software in a client machine and try to open it, the login is again asked.

The following code is used for internal login.

```
CReport.SimpleCrystalReportViewer simple = new CReport.SimpleCrystalReportViewer(); //
                simple.Show();
                CReport.EmployeeVisaDetail report = new CReport.EmployeeVisaDetail();
                TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
                TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
                ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                Tables CrTables;
                report.Load();
                crConnectionInfo.ServerName = db.ServerName;
                crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = db.DataBase;
                crConnectionInfo.UserID = db.UserName;
                crConnectionInfo.Password =  db.Password;

                CrTables = report.Database.Tables;
                foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
                {
                    crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                    crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                    CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
                }



                simple.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
                simple.crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport(); 

                simple .crystalReportViewer1.Zoom(1);
```

login asked when i open report.

Comment: I do have the exact same problem

Comment: How have you configured Datasource settings in the report itself.

Comment: No its given in code